# Two minor flaws of the election page

Tags: bug, election

I refer to [Math election page](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5?tab=nomination), specifically nomination tab.

1. There is a missing space at the very bottom:

   > currently eligible and displayedsee all 22 nominees

   If you are feeling rich, please throw in a period and an uppercase letter too.
2. Everywhere on SE sites, hovering over a text referring to time  shows the precise UTC timestamp. But not in this banner:

   [image: banner]

   which I think is a sufficiently important deadline to be stated precisely. This text repeats at the bottom of page, again without a precise time.

   (One can hover over "tomorrow" in "primary voting begins tomorrow" in the sidebar, but it's not obvious that the deadline for nomination is the same thing as the beginning of primary voting. In any case, the sidebar is out of sight when one looks at the page.)